# How can I explicitly set the timestamp when I logEvent with Firebase / Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm working in Swift with the Firebase analytics framework.

I see the `FIRAnalytics` header allows one to `logEvent:parameters:`

In the app I'm working on, we have a wrapper class `Tracking` that has the same API basically, but will log the same event to multiple analytics services. (Specifically, Adobe, Adjust, and GA)

What we're hoping to do is log these events locally, persist them, do a bit of post-processing on them at some point, then upload them all later, all at once. (Then flush our queue)  When we initially log the event, we give it a timestamp.

So is there a way to `logEvent:parameters:` with `FIRAnalytics` where we override the timestamp that it probably adds itself within that method call?  I'm guessing there's a parameter key-value I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to override the default timestamp that Google Analytics for Firebase uses, I don't think that's possible. I think your best bet would be to just create your own `my_custom_timestamp` field, and then use BigQuery to analyze your events based on that field.